# Array with Arrays that have objects -> format to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I have the following Array:

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 0,
    title: 'A',
    countries: [{
      val: "1173",
      label: "England"
    }, {
      val: "1172",
      label: "Egypt"
    }],
    companies: [{
      val: "7346",
      label: "Ab Company"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'B',
    countries: [{
      val: "1175",
      label: "France"
    }],
    companies: [{
      val: "8294",
      label: "Cd Company"
    }]
  },
]
```

What I want to achieve is:

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 0,
    title: 'A',
    countries: ["England", "Egypt"],
    companies: ["Ab Company"]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'B',
    countries: ["France"],
    companies: ["Cd Company"]
  },
]
```

My approach:

```js
const mapJobArrValsToString = (arr) => {
  if (!(arr && arr.length)) {
    return [];
  }
  const fieldsToAddLabels = ['companies', 'countries'];
  const clonedArr = [...arr];

  clonedArr.forEach((job) => {
    const objKeysList = Object.keys(job).filter((fieldName) => fieldsToAddLabels.includes(fieldName));
    objKeysList.forEach((key) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      job[key] = job[key].map((el) => el.label);
    });
  });
  return clonedArr;
};

const arr = [{
    id: 0,
    title: 'A',
    countries: [{
      val: "1173",
      label: "England"
    }, {
      val: "1172",
      label: "Egypt"
    }],
    companies: [{
      val: "7346",
      label: "Ab Company"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'B',
    countries: [{
      val: "1175",
      label: "France"
    }],
    companies: [{
      val: "8294",
      label: "Cd Company"
    }]
  },
];

console.log(mapJobArrValsToString(arr));
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: your code works fine - and produces the expected result - why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: According to your own snippet, the code already works as expected, as far as I can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build new object and add this object to the copy of the object.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 0, title: 'A', countries: [{ val: "1173", label: "England" }, { val: "1172", label: "Egypt" }], companies: [{ val: "7346", label: "Ab Company" }] }, { id: 1, title: 'B', countries: [{ val: "1175", label: "France" }], companies: [{ val: "8294", label: "Cd Company" }] } ],
    keys = ['countries', 'companies'],
    result = array.map(o => ({
       ... o,
        ...Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k].map(({ label }) => label)]))
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too:

```js
var arr = [{ id: 0, title: 'A', countries: [{ val: "1173", label: "England" }, { val: "1172", label: "Egypt" }], companies: [{ val: "7346", label: "Ab Company" }] }, { id: 1, title: 'B', countries: [{ val: "1175", label: "France" }], companies: [{ val: "8294", label: "Cd Company" }] }];
var keysFilter=['countries', 'companies'];

var result = arr.map((elem) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(elem)) {
        if(keysFilter.includes(key)) elem[key] = value.map(val => val.label);
    }
    return elem;
});

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps. Thanks! Happy Coding!